# How to load images in a stack view app widget in Android?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am creating a stack view app widget which will contain few images. The problem is I don't know how to load my stack widget with some images which are, say stored in an ArrayList. I searched for it and I read about **RemoteViewsService** and **RemoteViewsFactory**. Do I have to initialize the stack view (with the images) in the **onCreate()** method of RemoteViewsFactory? If so, then what's the correct procedure to do so?

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Below links might help you.

[link1](http://www.androhub.com/android-stackview/)

[link2](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/stackview/android-stackview-example/)

[link3](http://o7planning.org/en/10557/android-stackview-tutorial)

Comment: I want images to load in stack view **widget**, not in stack view activity. The links you provided are not for stack view widget. I had gone through them earlier. For widget, you have to use **RemoteViewsService** and **RemoteViewsFactory**, as described in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections

Comment: http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html#.WSbzA8aB2qA